# least number of planes intersecting a finite number of points in space, but not intersecting origin.

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, vector-spaces, recreational-mathematics, 3d

Let
$$\mathbb{R}^*=\mathbb{R}-\{0\}$$
and

$$N=\{0,...,n\}$$
and
$$\mathcal{M}=\{ A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^3\times\mathbb{R}^* \mid (\forall\mathbb{x}\in N^3:\mathbb{x}\ne 0)(\exists(\mathbb{a},d)\in A)(\mathbb{a}.\mathbb{x}=d)\}$$

(here $N^3=N\times N\times N$ and $\mathbb{a}.\mathbb{x}$ is inner product)

---

what is
$$m:=\min\{|A|:A\in \mathcal{M}\}$$?

---

Do you know any theorem that simplifies finding $m$?

Comment: You might be able to solve it for a few small values of $n$ and then look up the results in the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences. Can you solve the corresponding problem one dimension down?

Comment: However a 2d dimension solution is much simpler and may be generalizable to 3d.

Comment: Yes, that was my point.

Answer (score 1):

At least you can say that $m\le 3n$ by taking a single value $a=(1,1,1)$ and taking as $d$ all possible sums of triplets in $N^3-\{(0,0,0)\}$.

On the other hand you know that $m \ge n-1$ by taking $x=(k,0,0)$ and noticing that two of these points cannot stay on the same plane.